# ffmpeg glue 4 videos on split screen with preview

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 4 video files 480x1080 with audio - all different duration.

I need 1920x1080 video

```
_____________________________________________
|          |          |          |          |
|          |   first  |  first   |  first   |
|   play   |   frame  |  frame   |  frame   |
|          |          |          |          |
---------------------------------------------

_____________________________________________
|          |          |          |          |
|          |   play   |  first   |  first   |
|   last|  |          |  frame   |  frame   |
|   frame  |          |          |          |
---------------------------------------------
```

when first video done 2nd column video must start and first video must show just last frame, other left 2 videos still show first frame and wait queue

for example lets say we have these durations:

```
1.mp4 - 1:00
2.mp4 - 1:35
3.mp4 - 1:20
4.mp4 - 1:05
```

Also I can prepare screenshots of each video for preview frames (first/last)

Cant even imagine how to do this job with ffmpeg or maybe exists any simplier way for shell?

example of output video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdBd5-8uOTo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this can do the trick. It creates an empty 1920x1080 screen and then adds videos using the overlay filter

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -i vid3.mp4 -i vid4.mp4 -filter_complex 
"nullsrc=size=1920x1080 [base];
[0:v]scale=480x1080 [v0];
[1:v]scale=480x1080,tpad=start_duration=60.00:start_mode=clone[v1];
[2:v]scale=480x1080,tpad=start_duration=155.00:start_mode=clone[v2];
[3:v]scale=480x1080,tpad=start_duration=225.00:start_mode=clone[v3];
[base][v0]overlay[v0o];
[v0o][v1]overlay=x=480[v1o];
[v1o][v2]overlay=x=960[v2o];
[v2o][v3]overlay=x=1440[v];
[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]concat=n=4:v=0:a=1[a]" 
-map [v] -map [a]
-t 290.00 output.mp4 -y
```

Note that you will have to modify the duration to match the duration of your videos. I took the duration from your example. What you will modify is the `start_duration` in the video filers.
Make sure to also change the last parameter, the -t flag, to match the total length of your final video (sum of all your input duration).

The `start_mode=clone` option causes the first frame to be displayed when the video has not yet started
And last frame is automatically displayed at end of video

Comment: it looks like duration must be in seconds and -t too, for now it starts early and playing just 4.5 sec in total

Comment: also audio stream, not working on 2nd and next videos, but the way looks like true )

Comment: can u help with audio stream?